# Run ServiceStack from Sub Directory

Tags: servicestack

I am using ServiceStack asp.net core 5.5.  My client wants to deploy my API which runs inside a docker container to a subdirectory on their main API domian.

How do I pre-fix a sub directory so that everything loading in sub directory?

So right now everything works fine if I try:

```
example.com/ss_admin/
```

But client wants to proxy pass to sub dir so I need this to work:

```
example.com/subdir/ss_admin/
```

Also they need to access frontend like:

```
example.com/subdir/
```

I tried adding `app.UsePathBase("/subdir");` in Configure but that didn't work.

What is right way for prefix path of the API with a sub directory?

Edit:

The main issue is with SS_Admin.  Let me elaborate.  When This path is hit:

```
https://example.com/subdir/ss_admin/
```

It tries to load these scripts:

```
http://example.com/ss_admin/dist/app.css
http://example.com/ss_admin/dist/vendor.bundle.js
http://example.com/ss_admin/dist/app.bundle.js
```

This has 2 problems.

1. It is http so gets blocked for mixed content
2. It is looking in root of domain which is not mapped to this project.  It needs to look in sub directory

For these reasons nothing loads.  How can I edit this for autoquery admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way .NET Core Apps are typically configured when running behind external domains is that they're running on an internal port, e.g:

```
http://localhost:5000
```

Which sits behind a reverse proxy like nginx or IIS which uses a virtual host to map requests from the external `example.com/subdir` to the internal address where the .NET Core App is hosted, e.g `http://localhost:5000`. When using Docker this will be the external port exposed by the Docker container. It's not normal for the .NET Core App inside the Docker container to be running on a sub directory.

The docs on [Deploying .NET Core Apps to Ubuntu with rsync](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore-deploy-rsync) shows a popular configuration for hosting .NET Core Apps, whilst [Deploy .NET Core with Docker to EC2 Container Service](https://docs.servicestack.net/deploy-netcore-docker-aws-ecs) shows how multiple Docker containers managed by AWS ECS can be deployed behind an nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: Hi Mythz, can you check my edit please as I don't think that solves the SS_Admin issue.  Thanks

Comment: @Guerrilla Are you going through a Reverse Proxy? If you did requests to `example.com/subdir/ss_admin` would map to `localhost:5000/ss_admin`

Comment: yes, they are doing proxy pass on /subdir/ to <container address>:<port>.  ss_admin is pointing to root of domain, not the sub folder so nothing will load as root of domain doesn't have these files or belong to the project.  ss_admin needs to point to scripts in subfolder

Comment: If I go to example.com/subdir/ss_admin/dist/app.bundle.js then the file is there.  The issue is this is not where the SPA html is pointing

Comment: @Guerrilla Can you try setting `SetConfig(new HostConfig { WebHostUrl = "https://example.com/subdir/" })`? Otherwise you can modify a local copy of [AdminFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Admin/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Admin/AdminFeature.cs) and rewrite the `/dist` paths. Should work if you replace the `indexHtml.Replace()` with `indexHtml.Replace("/dist", "/ss_admin/dist")`.